# Disable GUI on BeagleBone Black running Debian

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

The Debian image for the BeagleBone Black that they have on their website comes with a GUI by default. I'd like to completely disable the GUI, but in the simplest way possible. It is used as a headless device and doesn't need those resources sucked up.

I've successfully disabled it, but I feel my procedure is breaking things behind the scenes. All I'm doing is:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

#### Questions

- In retrospect, perhaps `purge` would've been better?
- Can anyone see holes in the method, or recommend a better method?

Answer (score 4):

Add following to `/boot/uboot/uEnv.txt`:

```
## for BBB debian OS  
## this disables lightdm run from "/etc/init.d/lightdm"
## comment it to enable GUI
optargs=text
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the "runlevel" in a systemd environment to runlevel 3 like so:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
ln -sf multi-user.target default.target
```

#### References

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

Answer (score 2):

The main [download site from BeagleBoard.org](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) includes a link to http://elinux.org, click on it will show you a list of all images available. There you can download "console" images (instead of LXDE):

http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Debian_Releases

Answer (score 2):

Using the same approach that @Justin tried to show you can change your systemd runlevel to one that isn't graphical. This will stop any graphical UI from being loaded/used by your BeagleBoard.

***NOTE:** Many Linux distros now use Systemd and below I'm showing you how to enable/disable the various runlevels. Don't get hung up that it's from the Fedora FAQ on the subject, the commands are identical.*

From the Fedora topic on Systemd:

> systemd has the concept of targets which is a more flexible
> replacement for runlevels in sysvinit.
>
> Run level 3 is emulated by multi-user.target. Run level 5 is emulated
> by graphical.target. runlevel3.target is a symbolic link to
> multi-user.target and runlevel5.target is a symbolic link to
> graphical.target.
>
> You can switch to 'runlevel 3' by running
>
> ```
> $ sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
> ```
>
> You can switch to 'runlevel 5' by running
>
> ```
> $ sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
> ```
>
> How do I change the default target?
>
> ```
> $ sudo systemctl set-default <name of target>.target
> ```

**NOTE:** I modified the above verbatim's slightly by adding `sudo`.

#### References

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd